# Display Json Values

Tags: javascript, json

I am stuck with handling json values for a while now. I am returning json values in ajax call. Now i want to display the json in a specific format. For example, let the returned values be

```
{"Heading 1":["Content 1","Content 2"],"Heading 2":["Content 1","COntent 2","Content 3"],"Heading3":["Content 1"]}
```

I want to display in such a way that

```
<h4>Heading 1</h4> <input type="checkbox">Content 1<br><input type="checkbox">Content 2<br>
<h4>Heading 2</h4> <input type="checkbox">Content 1<br><input type="checkbox">Content 2<br><input type="checkbox">Content 3<br>
<h4>Heading 3</h4> <input type="checkbox">Content 1<br>
```

How Should I go about with this?

Comment: Loop through the object, put the key in an `<h4>`, then the value(s) in `<input>`s.

Comment: May be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: You may want to look into [one of the many available template solutions](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var data, container, key, curHeading, heading, i, checkbox;

data = {"Heading 1":["Content 1","Content 2"],"Heading 2":["Content 1","COntent 2","Content 3"],"Heading3":["Content 1"]};

container = document.createElement("div");
for (key in data) {
    curHeading = data[key];
    heading = document.createElement("h4");
    heading.innerHTML = key;
    container.appendChild(heading);
    for (i = 0; i < curHeading.length; i++) {
        checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        container.appendChild(checkbox);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(curHeading[i]));
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(container);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UwSU6/1/

Where this is happening in the `window.onload` event (like in the jsFiddle)

Comment: Thanks a ton..:) Suits my need.

Answer (score -1):

```
var json ={"Heading 1":["Content 1","Content 2"],"Heading 2":["Content 1","COntent 2","Content 3"],"Heading3":["Content 1"]}
obj = JSON.parse(json);


for ( evaluationHere){
    createTheElementsHEre()

}
insertHtml();
```

Comment: `json` is not JSON, it's an object.